# What glues can attach plastic to satin?

Tags: adhesives, costume-design

I need to attach some plastic beads ("pearls") to a satin headband. What will work for this -- hot glue? fabric glue? some other adhesive?

Comment: Very interesting. Is there a reason you're opting for glue, and not sewing?

Comment: It's satin over a plastic core, and I'm not able to get a needle through that hard core.

Comment: Could you post some pics, if possible? Do you have a Dremel?

Comment: I do have a Dremel, and I will post some pics tomorrow. (It's going to be modeled after Anne Boleyn's headdress [in this portrait of her](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/491/30) that I referenced in another question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [a good article](http://www.crystalandglassbeads.com/blog/2012/the-ultimate-adhesive-guide-for-swarovski-flat-backs-and-fabric.html) which considers various different glues and compares their performances when used to glue small crystals to various different types of material. It appears to be an updated version of [this slightly older article](http://www.crystalandglassbeads.com/blog/2012/swarovski-crystals-flatbacks-glue.html) from the same website.

Neither article mentions satin specifically, but the later one considers some similar materials, and the author does mention satin in response to queries in the comments sections of both articles (Ctrl+F "satin" on either page if you want to check). The advice given there is that either **Gemtac** or **E6000** would be the best glue to use for satin. E6000 is stronger and better, but has very strong fumes, while Gemtac is non-toxic and thinner.

[image]

I hope this is the kind of answer you're looking for!

Comment: My mother used to use [this Arlene's Tacky Glue](http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aamm_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-joann-product-catalog/default/dwe4b3ef78/images/hi-res/20/2018091.jpg) when she sewed heavily. I remember there always being a bottle when I was a child.

Comment: I got some and it took a while to dry enough for the pearl to stay in place (without rolling), which made the crafting process sloooooow. However, this glue didn't peel the pearlescence off the plastic bead (which the hot glue did) so it held better!